# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on gallery image classification using tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am developing an app to classify an image using tensorflow. There are two options 
1) Camera image
2) Gallery image
When I capture the image and pass it to classifier it is working fine. but when I upload the image from the gallery and pass it to classifier i am getting an error. and the error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelsAccess(Bitmap.java:1573)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixels(Bitmap.java:1514)
        at org.tensorflow.demo.TensorFlowImageClassifier.recognizeImage(TensorFlowImageClassifier.java:134)
        at org.tensorflow.demo.galleryimageclassifier.classify(galleryimageclassifier.java:70)
```

In the camera image classification, I pass the image as follows

```
public void classify(View v) {
        {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            final int INPUT_SIZE = 299;
            final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
            final float IMAGE_STD = 128;
            final String INPUT_NAME = "Mul";
            final String OUTPUT_NAME = "final_result";
            final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/stripped_retrained_graph2.pb";
            final String LABEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/retrained_labels.txt";
            final Classifier classifier;
            classifier = TensorFlowImageClassifier.create(
                            getAssets(),
                            MODEL_FILE,
                            LABEL_FILE,
                            INPUT_SIZE,
                            IMAGE_MEAN,
                            IMAGE_STD,
                            INPUT_NAME,
                            OUTPUT_NAME);
            final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            final List<Classifier.Recognition> results = classifier.recognizeImage(bmp);
            final long lastProcessingTimeMs = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            ResultsView resultsView = null;
            if (resultsView == null) {
                resultsView = (ResultsView) findViewById(R.id.results);
            }
            resultsView.setResults(results);
        }
    }//End Classify
```

This is working fine.

In the gallery image classification, I am passing image as follows

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            path = extras.getString("image_path");
            File imgFile = new  File(path);
            Bitmap bmp  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            final int INPUT_SIZE = 299;
            final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
            final float IMAGE_STD = 128;
            final String INPUT_NAME = "Mul";
            final String OUTPUT_NAME = "final_result";
            final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/stripped_retrained_graph2.pb";
            final String LABEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/retrained_labels.txt";
            final Classifier classifier;
            classifier = TensorFlowImageClassifier.create(
                    getAssets(),
                    MODEL_FILE,
                    LABEL_FILE,
                    INPUT_SIZE,
                    IMAGE_MEAN,
                    IMAGE_STD,
                    INPUT_NAME,
                    OUTPUT_NAME);
            final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            final List<Classifier.Recognition> results = classifier.recognizeImage(bmp);
            final long lastProcessingTimeMs = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            ResultsView resultsView = null;
            if (resultsView == null) {
                resultsView = (ResultsView) findViewById(R.id.results);
            }
            resultsView.setResults(results);
        }
    }//End Classify
```

Can someone please guide me how can I solve this?
Is there any issue in creating the image as I am creating "Bitmap bmp" image from the byte array in case of camera capture image and from image path in case of gallery image? 
I am stuck from last three days and tried different solutions but noting work for me. Please help me.

Comment: If you have confirmed that the byte array is stored and retrieved successfully via the intent bundle, then perhaps you could explain how the bytes were originally obtained?  If the bytes are corrupted in some manner then it might have some issues trying to reconstruct it later.

Comment: bytes are not corrupted. When I pass the image to the recognizeimage() function and debug the code I can see the image (according to me if I can see the image it means it is not corrupted? Please correct me if I am wrong? ). but when I get the pixels values like bitmap.getpixels(). all the values are zero. I don't know what is wrong? Can you please guide me.